# Datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to get DateTime.now in SQL stored procedure?

Can this be done with T-SQL or do i have to pass in the date with a parameter?

```
--Set Last download date

        SET @DateAndTime = ????????;

    UPDATE
        Valuation
    SET
        LastDownloadDate = @DateAndTime
    WHERE
        FormMobiValuationId = @FormMobiValuatoinId
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.100).aspx#GetSystemDateandTimeValues

Answer (score 7):

Use [`getdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188383.aspx). There is also a [`getutcdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178635.aspx) function.

Answer (score 2):

Beside using `GETDATE()`, You can use [SYSDATETIME()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx) [recommended for precision in sql server 2008 and above]....

Only difference lies between them is that in `GETDATE(`), the precision goes to `millisecond` whereas `SYSDATETIME()` do have precision upto `nanosecond`.

As you have tagged the question for sql server -2008, I would recommend to use `SYSDATETIME()`..

Note : `SYSDATETIME()` is not available in `sql server 2005`.